# bootstrap 4 collapse data-parent dosent close other tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

when you click on an image it opens a tab and if you click on another image while a tab is opened it wont close it and just stack the div on top of the first one.

what am i missing ?

https://jsfiddle.net/473m0y6z/1/

```
<div id="keystones">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#8005" data-parent="#keystones">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#8008" data-parent="#keystones">

    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="collapse" id="8005">
            <h5>Press the Attack</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="8008">
            <h5>Lethal Tempo</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Working from the duplicate question: https://jsfiddle.net/upxxkw20/

Comment: @ZimSystem Thank you, i can see my mistake now